# How to redirect iframe users?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, web

I have a website: galiro.com/summer.html
I want to redirect people who use my website in an iframe to the actual website. Is this possible?

Comment: Algorithm is: -> Check if the window and parent window are same. -> If they are, do nothing. -> If they aren't, change parent window address and start again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent iframe stealing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522097/prevent-iframe-stealing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
if (window.top != window.self)  { 
    window.top.location.href = "http://galiro.com/summer.html";
}
```

Comment: Isn't this an infinite loop? You just keep redirecting the iframe and the condition will be true all the time.

Comment: @Esailija: True, it should be `window.top.location.href = "..."`.

Comment: @Esailija: Good point, editing to fix.