# How to prevent any app to load my website in webview

Tags: javascript, android, iframe, webview

I've made a webapp but I don't want that any app load my website in webview.
How can I achieve this?
What can I put into javascript to check if the website is not into a regular browser?

To stop the execution in iframe I use to throw an `Error` so I just need a condition.

Thanks

PS)

Q: Why you don't just use [iframe protection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522097/prevent-iframe-stealing#5522130)?
A: WebView != iframe

Q: Does the webview have a [different User Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400935/browser-detection-in-javascript)? Or it could be edited too?
A: Yes, It can't be edited on iOS and then [detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37591279/detect-if-user-is-using-webview-for-android-ios-or-a-regular-browser) **but** it can be [edited on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586197/android-user-agent#5590105)

So... Is the Android WebView a regular browser that can't be detected?

Comment: This will work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-t

Comment: @SergioEscudero I was looking for something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400935/browser-detection-in-javascript ; but I don't now if WebView can edit User Agent

Comment: It is easy enough to restrict your site to your own mobile App. iOS and Android both allow you to set a custom user agent for a webview. Then on your site, if that custom user agent is not found, redirect to a "get the app" page. Not 100% sure to works as some could modify their own user agent to by-pass the check.

Comment: @Tiger I don't want to annoy people to download an app for this; so I don't want that other get the website into a webview on android. In android the User Agent can be [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586197/android-user-agent#5590105) so there is another way?

Comment: Well, Google stopped allowing OAuth login from a WebView, so it sounds like there is a way to detect it. (You may even be able to hook into Google, by trying to access the Google Login page, and see if an error is returned. Not recommend...)