# Block website from loading in native Android app

Tags: javascript, android

Someone have created an Android app using my website URL * (There are many online free tools by which Android app can be created by just putting website URL)* and have uploaded it in Playstore. The app have 1000+ install.

Problem is - my webpages have adsense ad and these ads are also appearing in the app which is violation of adsense ad terms.
So, is there any code/JavaScript which I can place on my website and then it will stop loading my website in any such Android app using my URL.

Comment: no, not really. If you think your copyrights are violated, contact google and they might remove the app from the  store.

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-t

Comment: same issue may you get solution from this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45806744/how-to-prevent-any-app-to-load-my-website-in-webview

Answer (score 0):

You can look at this answer to detecting a mobile browser:
[Detecting a mobile browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser)

but you should probably just report the app to the Play store for the reason you gave.