# Checking iframe is called from the approved domain?

Tags: html, iframe, execute

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to limit display of iframe from an external site to specific domains only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224286/how-to-limit-display-of-iframe-from-an-external-site-to-specific-domains-only)

What i want is simple. I want to prevent my website to be called from domains I did not approve.
Let's say only a.com and b.com can have a page with an iframe calling my webapplication wwww.mydomain.com/myapp.php. How can I accomplish this?

1st I was thinking about my web appplication checking the domain of the iframe's parent. Maybe that is possible, but certainly not easy, because of cross-domain restrictions.

2nd I was thinking of having the requesting page on a.com and b.com execute a small PHP-script first which writes some info to a file or my database, so I know the requesting page is on one of the approved domains. The question is how to call and when to execute the script?

Is placing a script tag or image tag with a src attribute a good idea? That looks like a fairly simple solution to me and no PHP is required. The requesting page can be pure HTML.

Should it look like this:

```
<img src="http://wwww.mydomain.com/myapp.php" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;" alt="Not an image"  title="Not an image"/>
```

What do you advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I did it and it works like a charm. The average user won't be able to access my web application.

Nothing needs to be done on the approved domains. Sweet!

Thanks to dda and jackJoe ( [How to limit display of iframe from an external site to specific domains only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224286/how-to-limit-display-of-iframe-from-an-external-site-to-specific-domains-only) )

```
<?php

  define('MSG_NO_ACCESS', 'No access');

  $acceptedDomains = array('mydomain.com', 'a.com', 'b.com');
  $referer=get_domain($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

  if(!$referer || !in_array($referer,$acceptedDomains))
  {
     header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
     exit(MSG_NO_ACCESS);
  }

function get_domain($url)
{
  $pieces = parse_url($url);
  $domain = isset($pieces['host']) ? $pieces['host'] : '';
  if (preg_match('/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i', $domain, $regs)) 
  {
     return $regs['domain'];
  }
  return false;
}
```

?>

Comment: What if they spoof the `referrer`?

Comment: Simple and working. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This question has already been asked.
[How to limit display of iframe from an external site to specific domains only](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5224286/1403437)

Basically you can, depending on your web server, you will need to restrict access.

With Apache this can be done in a .htaccess file

With IIS this can be done in 'IP Address and Domain restrictions'

If your on some shared hosting platform you might not have all that much control.

Comment: My bad. I should have search first before I asked my question. But your answer is very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A little PHP injecting some JS can go a long way.

```
<?php
if(array_key_exists('HTTP_REFERER',$_SERVER)){
  $referer=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
} else {
  $referer='';
}
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
var referer='".$referer."';
</script>
";
?>
```

This will inject the HTTP_REFERER into a "referer" JS variable. Now with that and the following JS code, you're good to go:

```
if (top === self) {
// not in a frame, no worries
} else {
// in a frame, decide whether referer is one of the guys allowed to display your web site...
// nuke the content, redirect, display a goatsee pic, etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing you can do to prevent this. Anyone with a server proxy can grab your HTML and re-serve it up as their own.

Rule #1: if you don't want people stealing your stuff on the internet, don't put it online.

Comment: I am sure you are right. Maybe I should have said "prevent the average user" from simply calling my website in an iframe.