# Allow a page to be iframed, but disallow it displaying on it's own

Tags: php, apache, iframe

This is a follow up to [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224286) about controlling on what site(s) a page can be iframed.

I would like to use the accepted answer, but when a link inside the iframe is clicked, the referrer is then reported as the domain that hosts the framed content. Is there a server side way of prevening the site from displaying if it is not inside a frame? (apache, php5)

Here's what I'm trying to acheive:

My server generates some content. We want to share that content with specific other websites. We do not want this content to display by itself. If at all possible, I don't want to rely on client side script because it can be turned off. (setting the body tag or the main wrapper div to `display: none` doesn't really help, as the content is still there, in the source.)

Comment: as far as I know there is no reliable way for the server to know what context it's being requested with.

Comment: cant you just reverse the conditions on the post you linked? i mean, check if the page has a window.parent, if yes display else display a forbidden error?

Comment: Test if the referer is from the page that the iframe resides in. If not, then load the page it's supposed to reside in.

Comment: @reikyoushin I know I could detect it client-side. I am looking for a way to know before  the HTML is sent to the client. I could probably come up with an ajax solution though.

Comment: there are things here that might give you some ideas.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6662542/check-if-site-is-inside-iframe

Comment: @Fred, That works until a link inside the window is clicked. Then the referrer is changed to that of the framed content, so if I disallow the generating domain as a referrer, I can never go past the main page. If I allow the generating domain as a referrer, then "open in new window" or "...new tab" puts the page out there on its own.

Comment: @TecBrat Got it. There are ways of disabling a link to open in a new window/tab. I saw this a few weeks ago actually, just can't remember where I saw this. Javascript would need to be enabled for this to work, and we all know that Javascript can be disabled on the client-side. I use CSS to hide content which is embedded inside `<noscript>...</noscript>`; works like a charm.

Comment: @TecBrat Instead of using an iframe, can you not just use an `include` file?

Comment: The iframe will be on other domains. (other servers that I do not control) So no, `include` will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that the server (or server-side code) can possibly know whether the page is displayed inside of an iframe.  The server serves page requests and has no knowledge of the presentation.

I think that the closest you can come on a server-side solution (in PHP) is to check the `$SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`

If you absolutely must restrict access to the script to a frame, you will need something on the client that can examine the presentation. A couple of solutions for doing this in javascript are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326069/how-to-identify-if-a-webpage-is-being-loaded-inside-an-iframe-or-directly-into-t) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925039/detect-iframe-embedding-in-javascript)

Comment: I had pretty much came to the same conclusion before I asked, but hoped that someone else knew something I was overlooking.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible for PHP to know if the request come from inside a iframe, because it will have the exactly same form it would have if made at the top level window.

Why can't you use includes? In this case, there's a simple solution:

```
if (strcmp(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']), basename(__FILE__)) === 0){
    header("location: index.php");
}
```

**Edit:**

What I'm saying is that with iframes you can't control the access from the server side.

Lets imagine you have your main page `index.php` and the page that is iframed, like `foo.php`.

When you do `<iframe src="foo.php"></iframe>` a new HTTP request is made to the server, and it is almost the same than the request made for `index.php`.

With includes, you'd only have one request. One of the parameters of the request parsed by PHP server is the script name. When you do: `GET /index.php HTT/1.1`, the script name will be `index.php`.

Putting the code I showe you IN THE INCLUDED FILES will prevent them to be accessed directly, you can just reference them by an include.

Comment: If I follow the logic of your code, then it does exactly the opposite of what I am trying to do. If I don't follow the logic of your code, then please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem solved with this:

```
$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if($ref == '') {
exit;
}
```

An iframe's referer is the parent window's url so if the page to be iframed does not have an referer does not load so you get want