# Dropbox API Chooser with JS for multiple domains

Tags: ruby, dropbox, dropbox-api

I want to user Dropbox chooser API for my Ruby on rails application(This is not web app, This will be installed as standalone).

Issue is in specifying "Drop-ins domains", which currently i gave as "localhost. But for the machines on which it will be installed "machine name" will be used instead of localhost. And i cannot keep track of all installations and manually adding those domains

Please suggest, Is there some way to solve this problem? Can i use chooser API without drop-in domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dropbox Drop-ins API doesn't have any way of automatically adding domains, or registering any sort of wildcard, but we're tracking this as a feature request.

For reference, one thing that does work, though it sounds like it may not apply to your scenario, is registering just, for example, example.com, which would enable use on any subdomain of example.com, e.g., sub1.example.com, sub2.example.com, webmail.example.com, etc.

Alternatively, you can embed an iframe containing the button, which would be hosted on your own domain. This would let you just set that one domain in the app options page. It would be very important that you then restrict the set of domains that you allow to iframe your button though, but this list would now be under your control so you can set it programmatically. For example:

[How to limit display of iframe from an external site to specific domains only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224286/how-to-limit-display-of-iframe-from-an-external-site-to-specific-domains-only)

Comment: Thanks greg, Absolutly, It would be nice to have a feature/option which gives opiton like "allow all origins" while creating chooser app. I'll see to the iframe option if it can help