# Authenticating URLs in iframe src and script src

Tags: javascript, iframe, embed

In our app, we allow people to embed videos using `iframe` or `script` tags. But we dont want to allow the people watching the video to *easily* copy these embed codes and post them elsewhere.

**For iframes** - what we've done is, in the `iframe` tag, we replace the `src` attribute's value with a proxy URL we have setup inside our application which simply redirects to the actual `src` URL. Besides this, it also does the authentication at this stage.

Clever people will surely be able to crack this, but this seems like a good solution for most cases since when they try to inspect the dom they only see the proxy URL and not the actual one.

**For < script/>** - I tried doing the same, but did not work out.
Eg. -

`<div id="wowza_player"><script src='//player.cloud.wowza.com/hosted/abcdefg/wowza.js' type='text/javascript'></script></div>`

Is there anyway to obfuscate or prevent abuse of these embed codes?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of what the script embed would look like?

Comment: With iframes the way you are doing is a good way to achieve that. With Scripts i think it is difficult to do it since it has to run on browser client. The only way i can think of right now is to minify it so that its not easily readable.

Comment: @BasvanStein added example for the script embed tag.

Comment: You could use a proxy that echos the content of the original url with a content header set to javascript.

Comment: @BasvanStein that seems reasonable!! Will let you know how it goes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case of iFrame, it can be possible to verify the domain that "call" the iframe using the referer. See [How to limit display of iframe from an external site to specific domains only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224286/how-to-limit-display-of-iframe-from-an-external-site-to-specific-domains-only)

Comment: Actually, I dont control the iframe's source application. It might be YouTube, Vimeo etc. So, there's no way for me to restrict those iframes from rendering in certain domains only :)